# Is there any way to trigger a network connection repair automatically?

Tags: windows, networking, wifi

I have a computer with windows 7 that I intend to use as server (it will at home and I may need to access it from work), now, problem is WiFi connection sometimes hangs, but after repairing it, it works OK.

Is there any way to trigger a network connection repair automatically from a script which will first ping router and if no answer then start connection repair, all without my intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two solutions on StackExchange to do this:

- [Repair network connections programmatically from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382998/repair-network-connections-programmatically-from-command-line)
- [How to launch a command on network connection disconnection](https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection)

On how to repair the connection: I would use netsh to bring the interface down and up again.

The better solution to your problem would be to determine the cause of the failed network connection. Reinstall or update your drivers and update the firmware of your access-point/router.